# How to change the color of clusters using R?

Tags: r, plot, colors

I am using the R for Kmeans Clustering, so I load the library (fpc), and using plotcluster method to plot the data.

```
clus <- kmeans(data, centers = 5)
plotcluster(data, clus$cluster, pch = clus$cluster)
```

So 5 groups of particles are plotted, but with default colors for different groups. But how can I change the colors of the particles?

For example, group 1 to some particular color and group 2 to some particular color.

There is a parameter called "`col`" in the plotcluster function, but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  A reproducible example would help yield useful answers.  Visit [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I tested on RStudio running on a Mac OS X 10.10.2 with the latest installation of the fpc package.

By no means am I suggesting you use these colors, but if you add the following two parameters I think you will be able to select the colors you want:

> vector of class numbers which can be coerced into integers; length must equal nrow(xd)

**clvecd** = c(1,2,3,4,5)

> vector of colors that correspond to your clusters

**col**=c("blue","green","purple","red","yellow")

```
plotcluster(  data
            , clus$cluster
            , pch = clus$cluster
            , clvecd=c(1,2,3,4,5)
            , col=c("blue","green","purple","red","yellow"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I don't really understand what the "clvecd" means. It seems that, it is the id of clusters. Just like my example, there are 867 rows in a dataframe, and they can be clustered into 5 different groups. Each groups needs to be colored with col=c("blue","green","purple","red","yellow") But if I make the plotcluster function like yours, it prompt out a warning message that "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length". Also, after "clvecd" added, the clusters plotted in different patterns. But if I put the "clvecd = clus$cluster", it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but hey. I had this issue today and found this solution.

```
clus <- kmeans(x, centers=5)
vcol <- c("blue","green","purple","red","yellow")
plotcluster(x, clus$cluster, col=vcol[clus$cluster])
```

NB :
If length(vcol) - centers = 1, last color won't be used.
If centers - length(vcol) = 1, points in last cluster won't display.